# HTML 5 Audio - What is the correct way to handle InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Here's some sample code:

```
try {
     document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].currentTime = audioStartTime;
     console.log('audioEl.currentTime: ' + document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].currentTime);
}
catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.message);
}
```

Sometimes the above code works other times it does not. My question is this what does the error "InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11" mean and how do I mitigate it.

The above code is part of a function that is executed with an 'onloadedmetadata' event. The browser I'm testing this on is Safari on OS X Mavericks and when testing the pages they are being served using OS X Server.

Comment: Could you possibly be making the mistake explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824487/html5-audio-testing-for-invalid-state-error-or-dom-exception-11

Comment: I you search for `"InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 audio currentTime"`, you will find that the error generally comes from trying to set the `currentTime` before the audio has finished loading.  You don't show us how this code that is causing the error is called, but this seems like it fits the symptoms because whether or not the error occurs would be a timing issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. How would I test to see if the time I'd like to change the audio to is downloaded / can be played?